# making application workign without SQL Server by data migration?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have to work on an desktop application which was developed with WinForms/ C#, SQL server and EF 4.

DAL has been implemented using Repository and UoW paterns. Data is being used just for read only purposes. Can you please adivce how Data base can be removed and application can be modified to work by using data from some files, XML or in memory collections. It is some chage to DAL required.

Please guide how it can be done usign least changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally converted my DB to SQL Server CE.

Answer (score 2):

Repository is an abstraction, so, you just have to write yet another implementation. Something like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
  IQuerable<T> GetEntities();
}

// this works with database
public class SomeEntityDbRepository<SomeEntity> : IRepository<SomeEntity>
{
  // ...

  public IQuerable<SomeEntity> GetEntities()
  {
    return dbContext.Set<SomeEntity>();
  }
}

// this works with file storage:
public class SomeEntityFileRepository<SomeEntity> : IRepository<SomeEntity>
{
  // ...

  public IQuerable<SomeEntity> GetEntities()
  {
    using (var stream = new Filestream(/* ... */))
    {
      var serializer = /* ... */;
      var someEntities = /* ...deserialize from file */

      return someEntities.AsQuerable();
    }
  }
}
```

Then provide this implementation to BLL, e.g., via dependency injection.
Moreover, you can put DI-container configuration into app.config, and make data source configuration more flexible.

Comment: I am not aware of repository pattern but this looks amazingly similar to IoC. Probably yet another way to implement IoC in application.